# Windows failed to start without the installation disc

Tags: windows-7

> Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software chanhe might be the cause. 1.Insert installation disc.....

I plugged in an external hard drive that used to cannot be connected to my PC. The only way I used to make it discoverable to my PC was deleting the IN.. something file so after I successfully plugged in the hard drive, I left it on a few minutes.

When I got back, I got that black screen. I tried everything, maybe. (pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, holding/pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> & <kbd>F9</kbd>) I just haven't tried inserting the installation disc. I just don't have it. Or maybe I do, but I don't know where it is. Does it come when I first purchased my PC? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### Preserve your important data (documents, photos etc)

You should already have several backups of your important data that you make copies of daily and which you keep separate from your computer.

If you don't, as soon as you get anything working, make at least one copy of your important data to an external storage device (USB stick, USB hard drive, DVD-writer etc). Preferably make several copies and check they can be read on other computers before proceeding.

There are other options for recovering your data (see other questions here on that subject) if you need to re-install Windows 7 or move to a new computer.

### Fix Windows

Try [booting in safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17419/windows-7-advanced-startup-options-safe-mode)

If that works, Try reinstating a [system restore point](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17127/windows-back-up-restore). I mention this because you got a message saying a recent hardware or software change may be the cause of your problem.

If you cannot restore from a system restore point. You may need to try using the [system repair option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17419/windows-7-advanced-startup-options-safe-mode)

If all this fails, you may be able to purchase a Windows 7 recovery/installation CD from the manufacturer of your PC. Using this may destroy any personal data you have stored on the PC.

### Make a repair disk

[Plan for the future](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17423/windows-7-create-system-repair-disc) - think of it as insurance.